# Reloading a gif image in UIWebview

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am loading a gif image in `UIWebView`. I have a refresh button to refresh the `UIWebView`. But when I am tapping nothing will happen. How can I reload the gif image in the same `UIWebView`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144895/set-loading-gif-in-uiwebview-while-its-loading.... see this link..it may help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:theURL]]
```

this will refresh the page with the gif image

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950205/how-do-i-reload-or-refresh-a-webview see this link

Comment: Iam loading image from my project bundle. Iam using loadHTMLString for loading.

Comment: the above link pretty much answers your question